# Does doubting the religious commitment of the Sahabah amount to kufr?

Tags: sahaba, kufr, doubts

We know that Allah has said that some of the companions of the Prophet had gone astray. Based on this, if a person were to doubt the religious commitment of a Sahabah, such as if he were to doubt if that if a specific member of the Sahabah were Muslim or not would that person be called a kaafir?

> Narrated ‘Abdullah: The Prophet said, “I am your predecessor at the Lake-Fount”. ‘Abdullah added: The Prophet said, “I am your predecessor at the Lake-Fount, and some of you will be brought in front of me till I will see them and then they will be taken away from me and I will say, ‘O Lord, my companions!’ It will be said, ‘you do not know what they did after you had left.’

Comment: "We know" <-- how do you know? Can you add a reference? But **if** a companion was a hypocrite and not a follower of the prophet by heart then I don't see a reason why the person doubting them would be a kafir.

Comment: https://marifaat.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/did-the-vast-bulk-of-the-sahaba-apostatize-after-the-death-of-rasulullah-s/

Comment: Make your question complete, include quotes in the answer not in the comments, otherwise your question will be downvoted/closed.

Comment: sorry @honey i added that link mistaking it for another.

Comment: https://islamistruth.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/did-the-majority-of-the-companions-apostatize/

Comment: You're "we know" is vague. You have to say: "according to SOMEQUOTE" we know..."

Comment: It is not "O Lord, My companions", it is ummah (followers). I dont know the source thou

Answer (score 1):

Well you should not doubt the religious commitment of any person anyways, as only Allah is allowed to judge people. Nobody has the right to say this is a muslim and this is not a muslim.

P.S : Focus on yourself and if you want to embrace someone's way of Islam, well, then think about it and if it really agrees with Islam and Qur'an. Allah will judge you, that's all that matter to you. Islam is so much a personal way of life. yes, it reflects to other and you get inspired from others, but in the end you will be alone in the day of judgment.

Comment: You said "any person" you mean we can't doubt the commitment of Saddam, Hitler, mass murderers who also happened to have a religion?

Comment: yes, nobody, you're not allowed to judge anyone, no exceptions.If you say X is surely going to hell, it means that you think you know what Allah will do, which is very wrong, nobody knows what God thinks or does.
Yes God is fair, and bad people are going to hell, but it just really not your business to say x or y are going to hell.

Comment: You're right no one but Allah judge, we can re-state for those who have *publicly* committed sins which Allah has cursed or disapproved in Quran. There are many verses in the Quran where Allah uses the term ***هل یستوی الذین*** meaning "Are they equal?"

Comment: What you said has got me thinking. If we are not to judge then we also can't say who's **good**. We would just have to be silent...And I personally think that's not a good conclusion

Comment: you can say, what he did was good, or this must be a good way to get close to God. The Qur'an is god's words, he can say that, but not you, for your eyes every person should be equal. If you start saying this one is good and this one is bad, you close to start discriminating against non-muslims.

Comment: so similarly we *can* say : "what he did was bad, or this must be a bad way to get close to God."